# How to split '_' with one more any one character in golang?

Tags: go

How to split '_' with any one character?

for Examples,

```
var one = 6221c62c67bc2a98ec6f713b_h32 
-> strings.Split(one, "_h")

var one = 12345c62c67bc2a98ec6f723c_c32
-> strings.Split(one, "_c")

var one = 12345c62c67bc2a98ec6f723c_s32
-> strings.Split(one, "_s")
```

How to combine these? (use regex? or any idea)

```
strings.Split(one, "_??")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex: `_[a-zA-Z]`, for eg

```
str := "6221c62c67bc2a98ec6f713b_h32"
a := regexp.MustCompile("_[a-zA-Z]")
fmt.Println(a.Split(str, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Replace:

```
strings.Replace("6221c62c67bc2a98ec6f713b_h32", "_h", " ", 1)
```